# What is theory behind graphs relations?

Tags: graphs, terminology

I have been trying to understand, what is the actual meaning of 2 graphs being:

```
Symmetric
Transitive
Reflexive
A graph being a subgraph of another graph
```

And other similar relations if let's say I have two graphs containing 1000's of nodes and edges. Then, what do these terms mean w.r.t to those 2 graphs?

Comment: I think you may be misusing some of the terms here, bringing them from relations and trying to apply them to graphs. Where is this question coming from?

Comment: I have been interested in graphs. What, aren't these applicable to graphs? I want to know if that's the case?

Comment: A graph in itself can be symmetric with respect to its vertex set based on automorphism relations, and there are types of transitivity on edges or vertex that can apply to a graph, reflexivity really doesn't make sense for graphs

Comment: Transitivity on edges, vertex means? Can you elaborate on those?

Comment: An edge-transitive graph is a graph $G$ such that, given any two edges $e_1$ and $e_2$ of $G$, there is an automorphism of $G$ that maps $e_1$ to $e_2$, similarly a vertex-transitive graph is a graph $G$ such that, given any two vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ of $G$, there is some automorphism $f(V(G)) \to V(G)$ such that $f(v_1) \to v_2$

Comment: Meaning that if there is a graph like, {1,2,3,4,5,6} with edges between adjacent vertices, then one of the automorphism of this will be, the same graph, flipped upside down. Then, which edge will form a transitive pair?

Comment: It sounds like you should probably read a book on graph theory, as your questions don't really make sense and you don't seem to have a good grasp of the subject yet. (Not meant to be offensive, that's how it is when learning any new field).

Comment: Alright, will do that, or if you know of a good link, please post it here. :)

Comment: Are you asking for definitions of these terms? Just google/wikipedia/textbook it; there is no use in us restating definitions here.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen the first three properties applied to a graph in the way that you are asking, however the final property, sub graphs, is strait forward.

By definition: A subgraph of a graph G is a graph whose vertex set is a subset of that of G, and whose adjacency relation is a subset of that of G restricted to this subset.

In more plain terms, if you have graphs $H=(V_2,E_2)$ and $G=(V_1,E_1)$ where $E$ is the edge set, and $V$ is the vertex set, if H is a sub graph of G then we can pair up each of the vertex in $V_2$ with one in $V_1$, With this pairing in mind, if we can then pair up each edge in $E_2$ with its counterpart in $E_1$ then the graph is a sub graph, if edges exist within $E_2$ which cannot have a pairing in $E_1$ then it is not.

Comment: Any directed graph (with self loops allowed) is a relation (and vice versa). So all of the three make sense for graphs, although they may not be the way we usually talk about graphs. Symmetry implies the graph is essentially undirected, transitivity that if there is a path from $u$ to $v$, there is an edge from $u$ to $v$, and reflexivity means every vertex has a loop to itself.

Comment: Yes all of that is valid, however look at what he asked, specificly that he was refering to two graphs in relation to each other, as in what does it mean if a graph is (symetric, reflexive, transative) to another graph, which is what does not work.

Comment: @Sasho Nikolov, What is transitivity? Can you explain again? Shouldn't it be something like, if there is a path from a to b and b to c, there will be a path from a to c.

Comment: Note that "transitive" has a different meaning in graph theory. A graph $G$ is vertex-transitive if, for every pair of vertices $x$ and $y$, there is an automorphism of $G$ that maps $x$ to $y$; it's edge-transitive if the same property holds of the edges instead. (Though these terms do always seem to be stated as "vertex-transitive" or "edge-transitive" and not just "transitive".) Note that an undirected graph with a transitive edge relation is just a collection of disjoint, looped cliques and isolated vertices.

Comment: @john what you are saying is trivially true for any graph (just glue the paths together). If the graph represents a transitive relation, then every two hop path is completed to a triangle: if $u\rightarrow v$ and $v \rightarrow w$ are edges, then $u\rightarrow w$ is an edge too. This implies what I said above (by induction). As David says, in graph theory you are more likely to hear about vertex/edge transitivity, which are symmetry properties of the automorphism group of the graph.